# Visual Studio build C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to build a C++ program. I downloaded the source code of the program on Nov 12th (e.g. Revision 10), and built it successfully. Then I updated the source code using TortoiseSVN to the revisions on Nov 14th (e.g., Revision 12), and got an fatal error when I build it: "Cannot open file: glew32.lib". Then I tried to checkout Revision 10, which was error free before. But I still got the same error. OK. Then I restored the whole folder of the code to Nov 12th, I still got the same error.

I am totally confused as what has happened, as it looks like I cannot even just go back? Anybody can help brainstorming?

[image]

Comment: It's trying to link to a static library and you don't seem to have it available. First off make sure you do (check the source directory), and if the error still persists, verify your linker searchpaths are correct (right click on project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories).

Comment: Thank you, szczurcio. I am not a C++ developer. I just uploaded the VC++ directories screenshot in the Question. Do you see any suspicious paths?

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. These are the searchpaths your compiler uses when it needs to find include files or static libraries for linkage. If the linker complains it can't find an input file, either you don't have that file at all (more likely), or you do have it somewhere, but the searchpaths don't contain that directory and hence the linker can't see it. In your case I think you should look here: http://glew.sourceforge.net/ - you should be able to download the relevant files.

Comment: I do have the file. The directory is \src_2015\3rdParty\glew-1.12.0\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib, but the the linker cannot find this file. Should I move it to somewhere else?

Comment: Oh, that makes it easy. You need to add a searchpath to "Library directories" - either a relative one (to where the source files you're compiling reside), or an absolute one (`C:\Users\James\Project\blahblah`).

Comment: Sorry. But I've added the absolute path to the "Library directories", but I still got the same error:"Error LNK1104: Cannot open glew32.lib"

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your VC++ Directories again?

Comment: OK. I see the problem. I added the path under release mode, while built it under debug mode. Now it works. Thanks for your help, szczurcio.

Answer (score 0):

Add path to your .lib file in "Library directories".

Then add library to linker via either:

1. #pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib") in any source file. Note, that this "visual studio-only" method of linking libraries, it wont work in GCC\Clang.
2. In project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependences - add glew32.lib here.

Comment: This is not the problem OP is having; if the compiler didn't try to include `glew32.lib`, they'd get undefined symbol errors. As you can see, the compiler is clearly configured properly, it just can't find the file.